# Scheduling actions to occur on specific event

Tags: python

I need to create a way for the user to change various settings, such as resolution or audio. This would entail running functions and changing variables. However, I do not want these functions to run immediately. I want to schedule all of these to occur when the user hits a button, "Apply changes". How might I go about doing this? What libraries could I use? I've already tried using the Queue library but it seems to have no way to run after a specific action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two versions of your application's settings, probably easiest if it's represented by a class, dictionary, or something similar.
Only when the user presses "Apply changes", the settings from the GUI overrides the application settings :)

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I'm running the functions (such as resizing elements / screen) inside of the part where I check if the "apply" button has been pressed. This if statement to check if the apply button was pressed might get a bit long over time, do you have any suggestion? If not, that's okay because it works :)

Comment: It's hard to help as of now, but glad you figured it out :)